# Spring boot - Unable to resolve jsp views

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to build a basic MVC app using Spring boot with Hibernate as ORM and MySql as Database. The problem that I am facing is that the **jsp views** are **not getting resolved**.

I get a **404** error when I try to fetch the registration form using a GET request with the following URL:

> `http://localhost:9000/users/register/`

This is the set-up that I have in my application.

**Directory structure:**

```
-src
  -main
    -java
        -com
          ApplicationStart.java
          -controllers
            UserController.java
          -repositories
            UserRepository.java

    -webapp
        -WEB-INF
          -jsp
            register.jsp

    -resources
        application.properties
```

**UserController:**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/users/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String Register()
   {
       return "register";
   }

}
```

**Application.properties:**

> server.port: 9000
>
> spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/Contacts
>
> spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> spring.datasource.username: root
>
> spring.datasource.password:
>
> spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
>
> spring.view.suffix: .jsp

**POM.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**MAIN CLASS**

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationStart {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStart.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the current setup of my application. Any help on how to resolve the issue is much appreciated.

Please comment if more information is required.

Thanks-

Comment: try `http://localHost:port/YourProjectName/users/register`

Comment: Make sure your pom packaging is war and not jar.

Answer (score 7):

Spring Boot has limited support for JSP, because of its use of an embedded servlet container. From the Spring Boot [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations):

> When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some limitations in the JSP support.
>
> - With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.
> - Jetty does not currently work as an embedded container with JSPs.
>     There is a [JSP sample](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) so you can see how to set things up.

Start by making your app an executable war, and make sure that you use Tomcat (check the log when you start the application). Unless you explicitly have stated you Jetty should be included, you are using Tomcat since that is provided by default. Alternatively, try change your view technology, which probably requires more initial work, but can significantly reduce the turnaround time during development, see [Hotswapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem recently while upgrading an old project that needed to have `jsps` as the view technology with `tomcat` as an embedded `servlet-container`. Caveat: Pick an alternative [templating engine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines), and avoid jsps if you can. But if you can't avoid jsps, and your application is not able to resolve them, at the time of this writing (spring-boot 2.x.x), ensure the following:

- Ensure that application [packaged](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) as a war and not a jar. Although it is not impossible to get jsps to work with a jar packaging, it is  a little complicated due to certain [limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations). You could just run them with a war package in a server or container just fine like: `java -jar war-filename.war`
- Verify that    your controllers have the `@Controller` annotation
  **BUT NOT** the    annnotation `@EnableWebMvc`. That's because you are using    `spring-boot` to configure WebMVC for you.
- Is your controller being scanned and injected as a component? If you have defined your controllers in a different package, maybe you are missing a `@ComponentScan` annotation?
- Are you jsps located and configured correctly? For example, let's say your jsps are located in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/, then your `application.properties` should have something like so:

  `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
  spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp`

Also, since you are using spring-boot, there is no need for your `Application` to extend the `SpringBootServletInitializer`. It will work too, but to keep it simple, all you need is a class like below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

FYI, the minimal set of dependencies needed are mentioned below (Maven Example):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <!-- spring-boot dependencies below -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jstl and jsp compilation support below -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I did as you said but still get 404. Why? In case you may need it, here's my repo: https://github.com/NadChel/CRUD_user_boot

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [@code4kix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5150013/code4kix), If all of this doesn't work, try adding below property in your application.properties file

spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false

Answer (score 0):

In my case that solved my problem

Location of JSP file: `src/main/resources` -> `/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/sayHello.jsp`

[image]

In `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
#For debug reason
logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

In Contoller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
 @RequestMapping("say-hello-jsp")
    public String sayHelloJsp() {
        return "sayHello";
    }
}
```

Intellij still show it as error, but it works
[image]

In IntelliJ, if you have the same configurations and it still doesn't work do this:

File -> Invalidate Caches -> mark first 2 lines -> Invalidate and Restart. Then it will work fine